# Javascript call method won't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, safari

I have a script written 3 years ago to track video player events that works perfectly on desktop browser, but it's not working on iPhone's Safari and Chrome. I have to make it work.

Here is part of the code. I've removed all other functions to make it simple and easy to understand my problem.

```
(function() {

  videojs.plugin('ga', function(options) {

    sendbeacon = function(action, nonInteraction, value) {

    };
    this.ready(function() {
        alert("ready");
    });
    return {
      'sendbeacon': sendbeacon
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

When I run it on a desktop browser, it runs without problems and the alert is shown.

When I run it on iPhone's Safari or Chrome, nothing happens.

What should I change for it to work on mobile browser too?

**UPDATE**

Just noticed that if I move the code to html header it works on mobile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

      videojs.plugin('ga', function(options) {

        sendbeacon = function(action, nonInteraction, value) {

        };
        this.ready(function() {
            alert("ready");
        });
        return {
          'sendbeacon': sendbeacon
        };
      });

    }).call(this);
</script>
```

When inside a file it won't work on mobile. Like this it only works on desktop browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $hostname;?>/js/tracking.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be?

Comment: How the callback that you pass into videojs.plugin() gets called makes a big difference as to what `this` refers to in the callback. It could refer to the videojs.plugin function itself, it could refer to the `window` object, it could refer to the callback function. `this` is not lexically defined. It is defined by the calling context of whatever function in which it appears